# Split the date in c#

Tags: c#

For Ex
You date enter in the various form in textbox

1. 12/Augest/2010
2. augest/12/2010
3. 2010/12/Augest

and out put is
three textbox First is day show= 12
textbox second is Months show= augest
textbox third is Year show= 2010

Comment: Or try http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=datetime.parse :)

Answer (score 5):

To parse/validate against three expected formats, you can use something like below. Given the pattern, once you know it is valid you could just use `string.Split` to get the first part; if you need something more elegant you could use `TryParseExact` for each pattern in turn and extract the desired portion (or re-format it).

```
    string s1 = "12/August/2010",
           s2 = "August/12/2010",
           s3 = "2010/12/August";

    string[] formats = { "dd/MMMM/yyyy", "MMMM/dd/yyyy", "yyyy/dd/MMMM" };
    DateTime d1 = DateTime.ParseExact(s1, formats,
                        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None),
             d2 = DateTime.ParseExact(s2, formats,
                        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None),
             d3 = DateTime.ParseExact(s3, formats,
                        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTime.Parse(String, IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs.aspx) or [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) to convert the string into DateTime.

Then you can extract the day, month and year using the corresponding [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_properties(v=VS.100).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
date dt date.Parse(txtBox.text);

txtBox1.Text = dt.Day.ToString();
txtBox2.Text = dt.ToString("MMM");
txtBox3.Text = dt.Year.ToString();
```

date.Parse might throw depending on the string you give it, but then you can fall back by trying to parse it using a different culture.

Edit: Added an M

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.Parse(s)`.  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx)

Then you can get the individual parts of a DateTime structure.

e.g.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("some input date string");
string day = DateTime.Day.ToString();
string month = DateTime.Month.ToString();
string year = DateTime.Year.ToString();
```